# Русские буквы и вопросы вместо них

Tags: oracle, mobile, windows-ce

привет!
столкнулся с такой проблемой.
есть самописная программа на C#. Использую для запросов dotConnect Mobile for Oracle/
Если просто писать в Label русскими, то все норм, а если делаю запрос в БД и вывожу в Label, то отображаются вопросы!
Подскажите где порыть...
ТЕрминал Memor X3, windows CE 6.0
спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

все! разобрался! надо в Строку подключения к базе данных написать Unicode=True